# Уведомления о новом комментарии в Таблице

Tags: google-apps-script

Скрипт для Таблицы присылает уведомление, когда произошло изменение в ячейке:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = event.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();

  if (index > 1 && sheetName == "Лист1") {
    var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var recipients = "xxxxx@xxxxxx";
    var subject = "Изменения от " + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var body = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + " Пользоветелем был внесен 
    комментарий.В файл " + ss.getName() + "
    " + ss.getUrl() + "
    Проверьте
    изменения.
    ";
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
}
```

Как уведомлять именно о внесении комментария к ячейке, а не ее заполнения?

Comment: Обсуждение в ообществе Диска https://plus.google.com/113699699955281625520/posts/1wkeg2K6e5K

Answer (score -1):

onEdit(e) реагирует только на изменение данных в ячейке. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit

Сам комментарий не вытянуть скриптом. Примечание можно, а комментарий нет.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-comments

Comment: Я имел в виду, что onEdit реагирует на изменение данных в ячейке. На добавление комментария он не реагирует. Но спасибо за ссылку.